# Duda en ORM Django

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django

Recibo diariamente un CSV el cual lo importo a MariaDB y limpio los campos con sentencias SQL por ejemplo en la columna marca si viene `SANSUN` con un `UPDATE` lo corrijo a `SAMSUNG` y así con cientos y cientos de sentencias hasta corregir todo el archivo.

Mi intención es darle una interface web tipo CRUD a esta tarea pero no sé cómo encargarlo en Django.

Estoy trabado cuando creo el modelo e importo el CSV, el proceso de actualización de campos que hago actualmente en SQL no se si lo tengo que hacer en una vista con todas sentencias del ORM (Python) de Django agrupadas en una sola vista o de alguna otra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Yo primero haría un objeto "Correcciones" que contenga una palabra a substituir y una palabra por la que se substituye (si es muy complejo un regex)
Cosa que me guardaría al inicio en un diccionario para no tener que preguntar a la DB cada vez.

Después por cada uno de las entradas haría un split de cada una de las palabras y por cada una de las palabras buscaría la coincidencia de la Key del diccionario y si existe (o pasa el regex) la substituiria por el value.

Ese proceso iría generando un objeto relacionado con la tabla donde añades los registros ahora y una vez substituidos los valores haria un save para su persistencia en BD